# Simulating wp.media drop area

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, uploader

I'm trying to make a simple uploader for my site, the client for some reason wanted a button and a drop-area to trigger the wp.media native wordpress uploader. I did the button just fine, now the droparea seems a bit more complicated, since the idea is that I drop a file on there and it opens the wp uploader and automatically adds that file to the upload queue.

I have never worked with wp.media, so I'm a bit lost... What's the best approach here?

Thanks in advance for the help!